# Objective C - Get a class to return a value

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I rarely ask questions, but this one is frustrating me as I can not find an answer anywhere!

I just need to call the function in GameChallenges.m and return the value to the view controller. GameChallenges.m will be called by different view controllers, thats why its separate. Please help!

I have a separate class file called GameChallenges.

This has a function/method in it:
in the .h

```
@class StatsViewController;

@interface GameChallenges : NSObject {


    StatsViewController* statsController;
    NSString* challengeTitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet StatsViewController* statsController;
@property (assign) NSString* challengeTitle;

-(NSString*)checkChallenge:(int)challegeID;

@end
```

in the .m

```
#import "GameChallenges.h"
#import "StatsViewController.h"

@implementation GameChallenges
@synthesize challengeTitle,statsController;

-(NSString*)checkChallenge:(int)challegeID{
    if(challegeID==1){
        self.challengeTitle = @"Some Text.";
        return challengeTitle;
    }else if(challegeID==2){
        self.challengeTitle = @"Some Other Text.";
        return challengeTitle;
    }
}
```

From a view controller called StatsViewController I am calling this method

in the .h

```
@class GameChallenges;

@interface StatsViewController : UIViewController {

        UILabel* challengeIDDescText;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* challengeIDDescText;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet GameChallenges* challenges;

@end
```

in the .m

```
[challenges checkChallenge:tempString];
challengeIDDescText.text = challenges.challengeTitle;
```

Comment: And what is the problem? I don't see a problem, besides your unconventional use of methods.

Comment: I can't see a question in your question post. But there may be a problem with `checkChallenge:` message you send. You pass with it something named `tempString` which is (I suspect) a `NSString` instance. But `checkChallenge:` expects it's parameter to be `int` so you basically cast `NSString` pointer to `int`. One can't expect correct behavior after that.

Comment: @hoha @fluchtpunkt 

If I simplify this. 
If in my GameChallenges.h i have:

`
@class StatsViewController;

@interface GameChallenges : NSObject {
 
 StatsViewController* statsController;
 int count;
}


-(int) initCount;
@property (assign) int count;`

And in my .m:
 

`-(int) initCount {
 count = 1;
    return count;
}` 

Then in StatsViewController.m

`NSLog(@"count: %i", [challenges initCount]);`

It returns either 0 of null/nil etc. it just cant read what has been returned. 

My question is can anyone tell me how to sucessfully return a value.  Thanks

Comment: Then problem must be that challenges itself is `nil`, check this with `NSLog(@"challenges = %@", challenges)`

Comment: @hoha Yes its come back with `2011-03-07 17:46:24.864 fallguy[7996:307] challenges = (null)` why is this? Thanks!

Comment: It's because you didn't set `challenges` property for your `StatsViewController` instance.

Comment: I have this: `@class GameChallenges; @interface StatsViewController : UIViewController {
 GameChallenges* challenges;}` THEN THIS `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet GameChallenges* challenges;` AND IN THE .m `#import "GameChallenges.h"


@implementation StatsViewController

@synthesize challenges;` What is missing? Thanks

Comment: Where does your `challenges = [[GameChallenges alloc] init]` take place?

Comment: erm.... where should this take place?? It doesnt at the moment

Comment: @rdamborsky ok ive just put that in and its now working! Ive no idea what that code does but its done it. Cheers mate

Comment: Well, that sequence is used to instantiate class and create an object. Check out Apple documentation [Allocating and Initializing Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite weird, I'd say this is what's happening:

`-[GameChallenges checkChallenge]` seems to expect an `int` and you call it with a variable called `tempString` that I guess is an `NSString *`. More likely than not, your method is ending without assigning `challengeTitle` and without a valid `return` value. Fix it with `return nil` as last statement and passing an `int`.

This kind of problems are very easy to solve using the debugger.

Also, have a look to Apple samples.

Comment: good point - what exactly are you passing as input for checkChallenge: ? If it is other than int value of 1 or 2, it won't return or assign any string.

Comment: @rdamborsky it not returning anything, even if I simplify the code. See my post above.

Comment: please point me in the direction of the apple samples, I cant find anything! Thanks

Comment: @scott-walker in Xcode docs, IIRC in the library home and in each Framework intro. There are tons of code samples. Check how they deal with these kind of properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginner in objective-C, however, code in the GameChallenges.m looks weird to me... Wouldn't this be better?

```
challengeIDDescText.text = [challenges checkChallenge:challengeId];
```

Comment: This still doesnt work. Ive tried this before. I dont know if im linking the two up right. Maybe If someone could give me an example of a link? I just cant find anything! Thanks